# How to suppress script display after PLSQL Error in SQL Developer (disable command/code output)

Tags: plsql, error-handling, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i run PLSQL block with an error, SQL Developer repeats/duplicates the whole script before giving error details. This is very gruesome as i for long script, i end up scrolling down after each error.

I need to find a way to disable writing the whole script into the script console. I checked Preferences and help, but didn't spot anything related.

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
BEGIN  
    xx;
END**;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PLS-00201: identifier 'XX' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I can also confirm that sqlplus does not do this - it only shows single line containing the error.

Comment: Don't know if it's possible, but you can always catch the exceptions and print out only the error message using `DBMS_UTILITY` functions like `FORMAT_CALL_STACK`, `FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` and `FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE`.

Comment: That still does not help with syntax in PLSQL unfortunately - which is the most frequent scenario when writing new code after a longer pause.
Will try different UI tools.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you didn't understand my comment clearly.
I advised you doing something like this:

```
BEGIN
    ...

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Call stack:');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_CALL_STACK);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'Error stack:');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'Error backtrace:');
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
END;
/
```

Comment: How does that help with syntax error in PLSQL script between BEGIN and EXCEPTION?

Comment: This is kind of a workaround for this - `How to suppress script display after PLSQL Error in SQL Developer (disable command/code output)`, and this - `I need to find a way to disable writing the whole script into the script console. I checked Preferences and help, but didn't spot anything related.` Isn't it what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, i was looking for this but catching exceptions only helps with exceptions, not for catching syntax errors in PLSQL (which is main reason i am asking this - interactive writing of PLSQL).
I searched all the preferences before asking the question too. 
Seems it is a deficiency in SQL developer (as Sqlplus does not do that).
Best workaround seems to be just syntax highligting and fixing the indicated errors before running the script. Not very good, but at least something.

Comment: Oh, looks like I misunerstood you then. If it comes to syntax error, I don't think there's any way to change it in SQL Developer.
But actually, printing out the entire scrpit was never a problem to me even if it had 2-3k lines.

Comment: Then your discomfort threshold must be a bit higher :) Repeating the whole script servers absolutely no purpose other than generate the noise and makes finding actual error message much more time consuming. *sigh*